# dc.js stacked bar chart, negative values messes up the layout

Tags: dc.js

I need to figure out this bug, my dc.js chart works just fine, except when I add  negative values to the stacked bar-chart. Instead of starting from y=0 it starts from the top of the stacked one and messes up the chart.

```
    function grid (selector,data) {
  var ndx = crossfilter(data),
      all = ndx.groupAll();

  var bar_bank = dc.barChart(selector + " .bank");

  var bank = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
      if (typeof d.bank == "undefined") return "";
      return d.bank;
      });

  var bankGroupBuy   = bank.group().reduceSum(function(d) { 
  return d.buy; });
    var bankGroup   = bank.group().reduceSum(function(d) { 
    return d.sell); });
  bar_bank
    .width(444)
    .height(300)
    .outerPadding(22)
    .gap(1)
    .x(d3.scaleBand())
    .y(d3.scaleLinear())
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .brushOn(false)
    .elasticY(true)
    .yAxisLabel("#BARCHART")
    .dimension(bank)

    .group(bankGroupBuy)
    .stack(bankGroupSell)
    ;
dc.renderAll();
}
```

This renders: 
[image]

but when i

```
return -d.sell
```

This happens:

[image]

Any ideas how I can fix it? So the stacked negative one starts from 0 and goes down, and does not start from the top of the first one?

Thanks in advance!

This is my csv:

```
time,bank,buy,sell,AVG_vol_price
2019-02-11,AVA,26378,138177,1.688
2019-02-11,NON,19340,13500,1.683
2019-02-11,SFK,0,43,1.74
2019-02-11,SHB,11300,498,1.692
2019-02-11,SWB,101200,6000,1.689
2019-02-12,AVA,125612,138612,1.683
2019-02-12,ENS,5000,0,1.702
```

Comment: Sorry, in principle you could customize the [stackLayout](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.stackMixin.html#stackLayout__anchor) to use a different [d3 stack offset](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#stack-offset), in particular `.stackLayout(d3.stack().offset(d3.stackOffsetDiverging))
`, but not all of these combinations work very well. You'd probably have to debug the library a little bit. :-/

Comment: Thank you!!
    **.stackLayout(d3.stack().offset(d3.stackOffsetExpand))**  this made it work!

Comment: Fantastic! I'm so happy to hear that.